# RxJS 6 switchMap Deprecated Symbol used

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, angularfire2, angular6

I've updated from `Angular 5` to `Angular 6`. Now I'm trying to update my code to make it compatible with `RxJS 6`.

```
.pipe(
  map(job => job[0]),
  switchMap((job) => {
    return job ? this.bookingService.findByID(job.property.id) : Observable.empty();
  }, (job: Job, bookings: Booking[]) => {
    this.mark_jobs_unavailable(job, bookings);
    return job;
  })
)
```

I'm getting warning on using switchMap that `Deprecated Symbol is used`.

These are my imports: `import {map, switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';`

Is there any alternative way to use switchMap in v6? Also, If I don't change my code the `rxjs-compat` should make my existing code work (which i have installed) but I get the following error with the same code but in RxJS 5 style:

```
.map(job => job[0])
.switchMap((job) => {
    return job ? this.bookingService.findByID(job.property.id) : Observable.empty();
}, (job: Job, bookings: Booking[]) => {
    this.mark_jobs_unavailable(job, bookings);
    return job;
})
```

`Error: Expected 1 argument but got 2`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The resultSelector function given as the second argument to `switchMap` is [deprecated](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#result-selectors-removed-or-deprecated). You need to remove this and achieve the goal using `map` operator.

The trickiest part here is to decide where to put the `map` operator. Actually the map operator to go inside the body of the function provided as the argument of `switchMap`.

The code without the result selector function will be something like the following:

```js
     .pipe(
          map(job => job[0]),
          switchMap((job) => {
            return (job ? this.bookingService.findByID(job.property.id) : Observable.empty()).pipe(

              // This is the mapping function provided as the alternative to the deprecated result selector function
              // This should be placed inside the body of the function which is the 1st (and only one) argument of switchMap
              map((bookings: Booking[])=>{
              this.mark_jobs_unavailable(job, bookings);
              return job;
            })

            );
          }     
         )
        )
```

Comment: But as you see I'm getting an other observable in switchMap and then calling a function based on both of the results. Isn't switchMap recommended for such situations?

Comment: Yes, but you have to do it within the first argument yourself; switchMap + map

Comment: Could you maybe provide an example?

Comment: I am also interested in that example.

Comment: `resultselectors` are deprecated. Here is the migration doc from version 5 to 6. In most situations it seems like an inner map should be used instead. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: If anyone are looking for the migration doc that @prolink007 posted, it was deleted and can be found here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/commit/661a9a3cbc184fec0ca93178a2713b1044142b1f#diff-2059af00cf2f5c11dc2744fcf996a7348169fabf1c7cfc00668db56482932611

Answer (score 5):

```
.pipe(
  map(job => job[0]),
  switchMap((job) => {
    return job ? this.bookingService.findByID(job.property.id).pipe(
      map((bookings: Booking[]) => {
        return {
          job: job,
          bookings: bookings
        };
      })
    ) : Observable.empty();
  }
).subscribe((job, bookings: Booking[]) => {
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who, like me, had not immediately understand why I could not use these overloads:

Overloads with `resultSelector` can still be used, but the deprecation is a warning of future changes, therefore, they can be removed at the next version of RxJS.

Use the operator `map` instead like above.